# Use [matAutocomplete] on my custom input component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

So I made my own `lib-input` component with custom styles that looks something like this:

```
<div class="input">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput [type]="type" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [(ngModel)]="input" (input)="onChange()">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Now I want to use this `lib-input` with its custom styles for an input field that uses autocomplete.

Something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <lib-input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

`<lib-input [matAutocomplete] ...>` doesn't work though, because `Property matAutocomplete is not provided by any applicable directives nor by lib-input element`, which makes sense, since my `lib-input` doesn't have `matAutocomplete` as Input.

Is there any workaround for this? I don't want to make a separate component that uses `<input [matAutocomplete]>` because I would have duplicate code for my custom styles, as well as the functionality my `lib-input` field has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually just pass the matAutocomplete through to your custom input. So in your `lib-input.component.ts`:

```
@Input() matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;
```

and then pass this to your `<input>` in the `lib-input.component.html`. The only downside is, that if you don't always want to use the `lib-input` with autocomplete, you kind of end up with a bit of ugly code repetition:

```
<div class="input">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input *ngIf="matAutocomplete" matInput [type]="type" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [(ngModel)]="input" (input)="onChange()" [matAutocomplete]="matAutocomplete">
    <input *ngIf="!matAutocomplete" matInput [type]="type" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [(ngModel)]="input" (input)="onChange()">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [tommueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423259/tommueller) is fine.

In my case my custom input implemented the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) Interface and I needed to subscribe to [MatAutocomple.optionSelected](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) to trigger the registered onChange.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.matAutocomplete?.optionSelected.subscribe(
      (event: MatAutocompleteActivatedEvent) => {
        this.onChange(event?.option?.value);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

in your component create new input property

`@Input() matAutocomplete: string;`

then pass it to your input , so your input will be like this

`<input ..... [matAutocomplete]="matAutocomplete"/>`

Comment: This does not work. `auto` is not just a string, it's a local template variable. If I pass it to `lib-input` as string, the input field doesn't connect to the `mat-autocomplete` that uses `#auto="matAutocomplete"`.