# How can you use MatAutocomplete on Ionic's 5 ion-input?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

[MatAutocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) seemingly can only be used on `input` and `textarea` elements. When you would build a custom `input` angular component with own style you could pass it through to the native `input` like described in [Use [matAutocomplete] on my custom input component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872590/use-matautocomplete-on-my-custom-input-component).

However, how can you use [MatAutocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) on an existing [`ion-input`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input)?

From what I see, when working with [`ion-input`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input), there is no easy way to access the native `input` like the answer above for custom input elements would require. You can use `getInputElement()` of [`ion-input`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input) after initialization of the template but from the [MatAutocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) documentation I don't see a way to initialize `mat-autocomplete` programmatically and then bind it to an `input` on the fly.

Am I missing something or is there any other good way to use [MatAutocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) with [`ion-input`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input)?

Comment: I'm approaching this problem now trying to convert a mat-autocomplete to ionic for styling (just a personal project though). Did you ever figure out a good solution on your end?

Comment: No real solution. Where really required we used custom components and dropped the idea of using ion-input. Not sure though if meanwhile there would be a better way...